# Excel VBA Evaluate not working, getting a #VALUE error

Tags: vba, evaluate

I have a VBA formula that works when I use the ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 function, which I used to test that I could get the result I want. This works as it should, giving me a comma delimited list.

```
ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 =      "=SUBSTITUTE(ARRAYTOTEXT(FILTER(VendSelect1,VendSelect3=LEFT(R[-7]C[-3],6))),LEFT(R[-7]C[-3],6) & "","","""")"
```

VendSelect1 and VendSelect3 are named ranges from a table in another tab

I am wanting to use the result of this formula as a string to use in a Data Validation list. The reason to go this route is the list will be dynamic based on a value that is entered in another cell, so the list will vary. I have the code for creating the Data Validation working, I just need to get the result of the above equation to be stored as a variable for that code.

I have tried using the Evaluate function to store the result but when I try to put that value in a cell to test that it is working, I get a #VALUE error in the cell. Is this just more complicated a formula than Evaluate can handle? Or am I doing something wrong? I am open to other suggestions to accomplish the same thing but I'm not a VBA expert and this has been the best thing I have found, so far, to accomplish this. Here is the code I have that is giving me the #VALUE error in cell D14.

```
Sub Test()
Dim FormTest As Variant
FormTest = Evaluate("=FILTER(VendSelect1,VendSelect3=LEFT(R[-7]C[-3],6))")
Range("D14") = FormTest
End Sub
```

I've been trying to get this to work for about 2 days and this seems to be the last obstacle to getting what I am wanting to do.

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: you need to use A1 not R1C1 in Evaluate.

Comment: When you use relative cell addresses with Evaluate how would it know *relative to what* ?  That's why you need A1 format.  Also you really need to use the `Worksheet.Evaluate` version instead of the (default) `Application.Evaluate` (which uses the active sheet for the context)

Comment: Also, you don't need the "=" at the beginning of the formula (but if it's there doesn't bother)